# Javascript/AngularJS force array data type

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application and need some advice on how to resolve this issue. I know it's probably an easy solution...

I am making calls to the Yahoo Finance API, where I receive one to many results, based on a number of factors.

My issue is that I want to run a .forEach loop, iterating over each result. This is working fine, except if there is only one result the .forEach function isn't recognised because the data type of the result set is an object, not an array of objects.

Any advice on how to make sure that the data is always an array of objects, even if only one result is returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the value is an array, if it's not, put it in an array:

```
data = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Derek.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the result is an array or not:

```
if (!angular.isArray(result)) {
    result = [result];
}
```